# Without defining a new command for each setting, is it possible to pass the set of settings to the optional argument of lstinputlisting ?

Tags: listings

## Screenshot

[image]

---

## Scenario

I want to define two sets of settings for `\lstinputlisting`--One setting for CSharp A and the other one for CSharp B. They are different only in the color settings.

```
\def\CSharpSettingsA%
{%
 \lstset%
 {%
  language={[Sharp]C},
  literate={ï}{}0{»}{}0{¿}{}0,
  backgroundcolor=\color{White},
   basicstyle=\scriptsize\color{Black}\ttfamily,
   keywordstyle=\color{Orange},
   identifierstyle=\color{Cyan},
   stringstyle=\color{Red}, 
   commentstyle=\color{Green}% 
 }
}

\def\CSharpSettingsB%
{%
 \lstset%
 {%
  language={[Sharp]C},
  literate={ï}{}0{»}{}0{¿}{}0,
  backgroundcolor=\color{Black},
   basicstyle=\scriptsize\color{White}\ttfamily,
   keywordstyle=\color{Orange},
   identifierstyle=\color{Cyan},
   stringstyle=\color{Red}, 
   commentstyle=\color{Green}% 
 }
}
```

There is a common setting as well.

```
\lstset%
{%
 breaklines=true,
 tabsize=2,  
 showstringspaces=false,
 aboveskip=0pt,
 belowskip=0pt%
}
```

**NOTE:** because each set  contains many key-value pairs, it is not good idea to pass those key-value pairs directly to the optional argument of  `\lstinputlisting`.

In the preamble, I define two commands as follows:

```
\newcommand{\InputCSharpA}[1]{{\CSharpSettingsA\lstinputlisting{#1}}}
\newcommand{\InputCSharpB}[1]{{\CSharpSettingsB\lstinputlisting{#1}}}
```

And in the document body, I switch between them as follows:

```
\begin{document}
\InputCSharpA{CSharp/MyCode/Program.cs}

\InputCSharpB{CSharp/MyCode/Program.cs}
\end{document}
```

---

## Question

Without defining a newcommand for each setting, is it possible to pass the set of settings to the optional argument of `lstinputlisting` ?

Such as `\lstinputlisting[key=CSharpSettingsA]{}` for example.

---

## Complete Minimal Code

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset%
{%
 breaklines=true,
 tabsize=2,  
 showstringspaces=false,
 aboveskip=0pt,
 belowskip=0pt%
}

\def\CSharpSettingsA%
{%
 \lstset%
 {%
  language={[Sharp]C},
  literate={ï}{}0{»}{}0{¿}{}0,
  backgroundcolor=\color{White},
   basicstyle=\scriptsize\color{Black}\ttfamily,
   keywordstyle=\color{Orange},
   identifierstyle=\color{Cyan},
   stringstyle=\color{Red}, 
   commentstyle=\color{Green}% 
 }
}

\def\CSharpSettingsB%
{%
 \lstset%
 {%
  language={[Sharp]C},
  literate={ï}{}0{»}{}0{¿}{}0,
  backgroundcolor=\color{Black},
   basicstyle=\scriptsize\color{White}\ttfamily,
   keywordstyle=\color{Orange},
   identifierstyle=\color{Cyan},
   stringstyle=\color{Red}, 
   commentstyle=\color{Green}% 
 }
}

\newcommand{\InputCSharpA}[1]{{\CSharpSettingsA\lstinputlisting{#1}}}
\newcommand{\InputCSharpB}[1]{{\CSharpSettingsB\lstinputlisting{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\InputCSharpA{CSharp/MyCode/Program.cs}

\InputCSharpB{CSharp/MyCode/Program.cs}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\lstdefinestyle{styleA}{...}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=styleA]
...
\end{lststyle}
```

and by the way: if you will make your listings more readable, use less colors ...

Comment: @Herbert, thanks for informing `\lstdefinestyle{}`. For electronic version I like using many colors. But for printed version, I will reduce the number of colors later.

Comment: @xsport: I were talking about electronic versions when I refer to less colors.

Comment: @Herbert: Can we use two or more defined styles at the same time such as `\lstinputlisting[style={styleA,styleB}]{}` ?

Comment: @xport: no, not possible

Comment: @Herbert: I tried `\lstinputlisting[style=common,style=styleB]{}` and it works. :-)

Comment: @xport: sure, it is the same as `[tabsize=4cm,tabsize=2cm]`, the values are overwritten

Comment: @Herbert: OK. Thanks. I will use this approach.