# How to use different lstset settings for listings?

Tags: listings

I would like to specify two different `lstset` settings in one latex file: one for java code, one for html. Is this somehow possible?

The solution of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654810/how-to-reset-lstset-settings-for-listings does not seem to be appropriate for my document because I have more than just one html listing.

Comment: [high possible duplicate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8621) detected...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Every `lstlistings` block can have its own formatting commands. So:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  Foo
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\sffamily]
  Bar
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{basicstyle=\rmfamily}

\begin{lstlisting}
  Baz
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

If you want to use two distinct listings and resetting the listings like this manually is a hassle, just create some new environments with `lstnewenvironment` for example:

```
\lstnewenvironment{sflisting}{\lstset{basicstyle=\sffamily}}{}
\lstnewenvironment{ttlisting}{\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}}{}
```

page 42 of the [listings manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) has the details

Comment: Precision : it's the page 42 of the listings manual.

Comment: @BenoîtFraikin It appears as if the `listings` manual has grown by a couple of pages since 2011...

Answer (score 14):

I use a style definition for every language, here is an example for makefiles:

```
\lstdefinestyle{makefile}
{
    numberblanklines=false,
    language=make,
    tabsize=4,
    keywordstyle=\color{red},
    identifierstyle= %plain identifiers for make
}
```

To include this style, I use

```
\lstinputlisting[
    inputencoding=latin1, 
    firstline=1, 
    %lastline=10,
    caption={[Makefile]Makefile, foobar},
    style=makefile
]{./src/makefile}
```

Other styles have another value for `language`(and other settings for keywords, tabsizes etc.)

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{tt}{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\bfseries,language=[LaTeX]{TeX}}
\lstdefinestyle{rm}{basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\slshape,language=[LaTeX]{TeX}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=tt]
\documentclass{foo}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=rm]
\documentclass{bar}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
  Baz
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I combine the flexibility of your answer with `\lstnewenvironment`, such that I can keep my custom environment, yet switch the languages e.g. `\begin{customenv}[language=bash]` and have another one like `\begin{customenv}[language=java]` and have another one like `\begin{customenv}` that defaults to `[language=java]` or just plain without syntax highlighting?