# Combine listings package with my own environment

Tags: listings, environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use different lstset settings for listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25471/how-to-use-different-lstset-settings-for-listings)

I have defined my own environment as:

```
\newenvironment{codegui}[3]{%
\def\tmplanguage{#1}\relax
\def\tmpshowspaces{#2}\relax
\def\tmpshowtabs{#3}\relax
\lstset{language={\tmplanguage},%
showspaces={\tmpshowspaces}, 
showtabs={\tmpshowtabs}, tab=\rightarrowfill,
stepnumber=1, 
numbersep=5pt, 
keywordstyle=\bfseries, 
stringstyle=\ttfamily,
numbers=left, 
numberstyle=\tiny
}
\relax
\begin{lstlisting}
}{%
\end{lstlisting}
}
```

and when I run it in document such as:

```
\begin{codegui}{C}{true}{true}
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
        printf("hello world");
        return 0;
}
\end{codegui}
```

I have erros:

```
! Package Listings Error: language C undefined.
! Emergency stop.
```

I try to find out but I can't. Please help me!

Addendum:

- parameter `#1` is C or Matlab,
- parameter `#2` is true or false,
- parameter `#3` is same as `#2`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250342/combine-listings-package-with-my-own-enviroment?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 1):

```
\lstnewenvironment{codegui}[3]{%
\lstset{language={#1},%
showspaces={#2},
showtabs={#3}, tab=\rightarrowfill, 
stepnumber=1,
numbersep=5pt, 
keywordstyle=\bfseries, 
stringstyle=\ttfamily,
numbers=left, 
numberstyle=\tiny
}\relax
}{%
}
```

I use `\lstnewenvironment` for the definition, and it works well.