# An environment for C-code

Tags: listings

I am trying to create an environment specifically for C-code, but when I compile the document below, LaTeX just hangs. I'm running MiKTeX 2.9 if that matters. Is `lstlistings` one of those environments (as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72983/alias-for-verbatim-environment), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13042/defining-a-shorthand-for-amsmaths-align-environment-as-commands) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/making-a-new-environment-combining-equation-and-split/3205#3205)) for which this is impossible?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{listings}

    \newenvironment{ccode}{\begin{lstlisting}[language = C]}{\end{lstlisting}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language = C]
printf("Hello, world!\n");
\end{lstlisting}

%\begin{ccode}
%printf("Hello, world!\n");
%\end{ccode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to create your own environment using [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)'s `\lstnewenvironment` (as described in the [`listings` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), section **4.16 Environments**, p 41 onward). Possible duplicate of [Combine listings package with my own environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44431/5764)...